# Gunicorn3 not starting with systemd

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, gunicorn

My systemd gunicorn3 configuration looks like this in `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn daemon for Django
Before=nginx.service
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/django/betadmin/current
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn --name=betadmin --pythonpath=/home/django/betadmin/current --bind unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py betadmin.wsgi:application
Restart=always
SyslogIdentifier=gunicorn
User=django
Group=django


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My Django installation is located in: `/home/django/betadmin/current`

I have added aliases for pip3 and gunicorn3 in `~/.bash_aliases`

```
alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3
alias gunicorn=gunicorn3
```

My nginx site configuration is located here: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django`

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/betadmin/current/betadmin/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/betadmin/current/betadmin/static;
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;

            proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

}
```

If I run

`sudo service gunicorn status`

```
● gunicorn.service - Gunicorn daemon for Django
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-11-07 15:27:18 UTC; 16min ago
  Process: 2783 ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn --name=betadmin --pythonpath=/home/django/betadmin/current --bind unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py betadmin.wsgi:application (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2783 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 07 15:27:18 django-admin-panel systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 07 15:27:18 django-admin-panel systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 07 15:27:18 django-admin-panel systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 07 15:27:18 django-admin-panel systemd[1]: Stopped Gunicorn daemon for Django.
Nov 07 15:27:18 django-admin-panel systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 07 15:27:18 django-admin-panel systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 07 15:27:18 django-admin-panel systemd[1]: Failed to start Gunicorn daemon for Django.
```

I am not sure what is the problem? Can anyone suggest? I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I want to run Django using python3.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to run `gunicorn` command in shell? Does it work?

Comment: Why is your working directory the same as the python directory? Isn't that weird? Also, make sure you have permissioned (chmod) `unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket` properly for the bind

Comment: @ScottSkiles permissions are okay for `/home/django/` folder. `gunicorn.socket` is created when gunicorn is working

Comment: @sipp11 if I run `gunicorn betadmin.wsgi` it works.

Comment: @sipp11 - I'd recommend adding options to the command line until it fails and you can pinpoint the source of the problem.